# Can Indians travel to Canada with a valid visa on an old passport as of 2021-2022?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, canada

Mom (Indian) has a new passport and a valid Canadian visa on an old passport. She was in touch with an agent to buy flight tickets, but apparently this guy told mama that she is not allowed to travel to Canada with a valid visa on an expired passport.

I did a simple google search and apparently one is allowed to travel Canada in such cases. I am just looking to reconfirm it.

Thanks

Comment: @Traveller Thanks but I just have to be sure that as of 2021-2022 and for Indians it's ok.

Comment: If there isn't anything in that linked answer that says "except for Indians" then it's OK.